# Sharing with UIActivityViewController, Message not working with UIImage on iPhone 6

Tags: ios, iphone-6

We are able to share `UIImage` with `NSString` with Message using the following code:

```
NSString *string = @"String";
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image.png"];
UIActivityViewController *avc =
[[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[string, image]
                                  applicationActivities:nil];
[self.navigationController presentViewController:avc
                                        animated:YES
                                      completion:nil];
```

I have tested with a number of devices and they are all working fine except for the iPhone 6. Any idea what's going on?

P.S.: If I remove the `image` from activity items list, iPhone 6 works fine as well. But we do want to image to work though.

[image]
[image]

With Image                                      Without UIImage

Comment: Have you tried giving the file URL to image instead of the `UIImage` itself?

Comment: i have same problem with UIActivityViewController but twitter and facebook. Someone says it's iOS8.3 bug and reported

Comment: @vichevstefan, could you give a reference?

Comment: @keithbhunter, yes, just did. Message is available, however, image is not attached. any idea?